# Graphhopper exclude some roads

Tags: graphhopper

I need to exclude some roads from routing.
I solve this problem implementing it with EdgefFilter
Or Is it better to use Weeighting interface?
Thanks
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

This example is documented in the [weighting docs](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/0.4/docs/core/weighting.md) so Weighting is perfect. But it could be done with an EdgeFilter too, although the Weighting is more powerful and you could e.g. introduce a high penalty instead of 100% blocking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my use case i have to avoid some stradal events, like man at work or car accidents. So i've  thought use EdgeFilter is better. Best regards, Antonio